# Unity firebase black screen

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Unity project for Android. When I build and run the app goes to a black screen after the Unity splash screen.

If I disable the script that downloads URLs from Firebase, the app runs perfectly.

Only the scene with the download script is having this issue, all other scenes run fine.

This is the script for downloading the URLs for images and audio.

```
 void Start()
{
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            // Set a flag here indiciating that Firebase is ready to use by your
            // application.
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
        }
    });

    //URL to Firebase Database
    FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://fir-web-login-f0757.firebaseio.com/");

    // Get the root reference location of the database.
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

    //Data snapshot to store query
    DataSnapshot _data;

    //Query entire database and store in variable;
    reference.OrderByKey().LimitToFirst(100).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            //Handle error
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            //Data snapshot of database
            _data = task.Result;

            //Each course in database
            foreach (DataSnapshot d in _data.Children)
            {
                //Each hole in course
                foreach(DataSnapshot e in d.Children)
                {
                    //Each section of the course    
                    foreach(DataSnapshot h in e.Children)
                    {
                        //Each URL
                        foreach(DataSnapshot u in h.Children)
                        {
                            //Each folder(image or audio)
                            foreach (DataSnapshot c in u.Children)
                            {
                                //If the key is "image"
                                if (c.Reference.Parent.Key.Equals("image"))
                                {
                                    //Write value of DB entry to ArrayList
                                    GameMaster.m_holes.Add(c.Value);
                                }
                                //If the key is "audio"
                                if (c.Reference.Parent.Key.Equals("audio"))
                                {
                                    //Write value of DB entry to ArrayList
                                    GameMaster.m_audio_files.Add(c.Value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too,
You need to initialize firebase SDK and ech services just one time in first scene.

Make sure don't initial the Firebase SDK and services several times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've downloaded the latest google-services.json from the Firebase project, and rebuilt the Untiy project and did a Build and run, but I am still getting the same issue, is there something I am missing with the initialization?

Comment: I checked back through my scripts and was Initializing the SDK on every load of the app. Thanks!